# Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

I am new in this world of programming. I'm trying to make an app with flutter and I'm having a problem that I can't find the solution
On the screen that allows assigning user permissions, when selecting the button that assigns them, I receive the following error message:

```
I/flutter ( 6171): Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
 I/flutter ( 6171): SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0
 I/flutter ( 6171):
```

I am using a model and a provider which I leave below.
I appreciate if someone can help me.

Rol model

```
import 'dart:convert';

Rol rolFromJson(String str) => Rol.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String rolToJson(Rol data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Rol {

  String id;
  String name;
  String route;
  String idUser;
  String idRol;
  List<Rol> roles;
  List<Rol> toList = [];

  Rol({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.route,
    this.idUser,
    this.idRol,
    this.roles,
  });

  factory Rol.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Rol(
    id: json["id"] is int ? json['id'].toString() : json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    route: json["route"],
    idUser: json["id_user"] ?? "",
    idRol: json["id_rol"] ?? "",
    roles: json["roles"] == null ? [] : List<Rol>.from(json['roles'].map((model) => Rol.fromJson(model))) ?? [],
  );

  Rol.fromJsonList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList == null) return;
    jsonList.forEach((item) {
      Rol rol = Rol.fromJson(item);
      toList.add(rol);
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "route": route,
    "id_user": idUser,
    "id_rol": idRol,
    "roles": roles,
  };
}
```

Roles provider

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/api/environment.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/response_api.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/rol.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/my_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/shared_pref.dart';

class RolesProvider {

  String _url = Environment.API_DELIVERY;
  String _api = 'api/roles';
  BuildContext context;
  User sessionUser;

  Future init(BuildContext context, {User sessionUser}) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sessionUser = sessionUser;
  }

  Future<List<Rol>> getRoles() async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/getAll');
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

      if (res.statusCode == 401) { // NO AUTORIZADO
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
      }

      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      Rol rol = Rol.fromJsonList(data);
      return rol.toList;
    } catch(e) {
      print('ERROR: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<ResponseApi> assignRol(Rol rol) async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/assign');
      String bodyParams = json.encode(rol);
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: bodyParams);
      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      ResponseApi responseApi = ResponseApi.fromJson(data);
      return responseApi;
    }
    catch(e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Roles Assign Controller

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/rol.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/provider/roles_provider.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/provider/users_provider.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/shared_pref.dart';

class AdministratorRolesAssignController {

  BuildContext context;
  Function refresh;

  SharedPref _sharedPref = new SharedPref();

  RolesProvider _rolesProvider = new RolesProvider();
  UsersProvider _usersProvider = new UsersProvider();

  User user;
  List<User> users = [];
  String idUser;

  Rol rol;
  List<Rol> roles = [];
  String idRol;

  Future init(BuildContext context, Function refresh) async {
    this.context = context;
    this.refresh = refresh;

    user = User.fromJson(await _sharedPref.read('user'));
    _rolesProvider.init(context, sessionUser: user);
    _usersProvider.init(context, sessionUser: user);
    getUsers();
    getRoles();
    refresh();
  }

  void getUsers() async {
    users = await _usersProvider.getAllUsers();
    refresh();
  }

  void getRoles() async {
    roles = await _rolesProvider.getRoles();
    refresh();
  }

  void assignRol() async {

    rol?.idUser = idUser;
    rol?.idRol = idRol;
    await _rolesProvider.assignRol(rol);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a return missing in the if and it continues to try to decode the body, which came up with the 401 status. Try to add the return at the end of the if.

```
if (res.statusCode == 401) { // NO AUTORIZADO
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
        return;
      }
```